# how to can install mininet v2.0.0 on ubuntu 14.4?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mininet, sdn

how to can install mininet v2.0.0 on ubuntu 14.4?

I've installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine (vmware workstation) ubuntu version 14.4, now I want to install the mininet v2.0.0,but I have no solution, please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: You can download the mininet VM from mininet.org. This virtual machine includes everything that you need to run mininet on Ubuntu 14.04. There is no need to create Ubuntu machine separately and then install mininet on that.

Answer (score 1):

Please following this [source](http://mininet.org/download/)

```
#/bin/bash
git clone http://github.com/mininet/mininet && cd mininet
git checkout -b 2.0.0 2.0.0
./util/install.sh -a
```